# UIScrollView contentSize height equal its frame height, why there is still a scroll bar?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

[image: problem]

I config scrollView contentSize same as its frame height(I also test <), Why scorll bar still shown, it seems that the scrollview content size is not what I configed in code.

Comment: Are you able to scroll?

Comment: Yes, it can be scrolled, at right side, there is a scroll bar.

Comment: Well, then the content size is getting set somewhere else then, isn't it?  Either in your code or by adding a subview.  Try moving the contentsize line to *after* adding logoview.

Comment: as your photo shown, your height cannot be 300 , because status bar is 20 , and your view is 300 ,so total is 320 , and the width is 320 , so it should be a square , but your photo is not a square , I think your frames height must be resized

Comment: @Guo Luchuan ,I found the problem. I use the latest XCODE, and it default use "Auto Layout" feature in InterfaceBuilder for View layout. I disable it and got what I want.

Comment: @qichunren Congratulation

Answer (score 0):

I think you are place scroll view in view with size for Retina 4 inch, and scroll view automaticaly resized.

add line in `viewDidLoad` method

```
self.mainScrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

or set up right autoresizing mask in IB.

Comment: I found the problem. I use the latest XCODE, and it default use "Auto Layout" feature in InterfaceBuilder for View layout. I disable it and got what I want.